# JSON Data Manipulation

Tags: json, swift, post, networking, alamofire

I am trying to pass variables into a JSON value to be sent in a post request using Alamofire. The first example is how the JSON value needs to look, however when the variables are passed the JSON actually looks like the second example. Does anyone know what is going wrong, or how to fix this?

Correct JSON:

```
{   "gender": "male",   
    "dob": "08 Jul 2001",   
    "loyalty_points": "2",  
    "barber_type": "1",     
    "account": {        
        "first_name": "Bob",        
        "last_name": "Smith",       
        "email": "bob@live.com",        
        "password": "1234",         
        "timestamp": "2016-07-08 20:26:13 +0000"    
    } 
}
```

Incorrect JSON:

```
[  "loyalty_points": 0, 
   "account": {
       email = "bob@live.com";
       "first_name" = Bob;
       "last_name" = Smith;
       password = 1234;
       timestamp = "2016-07-08 20:26:13 +0000";
   }, 
   "gender": Male, 
   "barber_type": 2, 
   "dob": 08 Jul 2001
]
```

Swift code:

```
let account: [String: AnyObject] = [ "first_name": firstName!, "last_name": lastName!, "email": email!, "password": password!, "timestamp": NSDate()]

let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [ "gender": gender!, "dob": date!, "loyalty_points": "0", "barber_type": barberType!, "account": account]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "api.exampledomain.co.uk/v1/user";, parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)
```

Comment: so what about the code that's supposed to be doing the conversion ?

Comment: What do you consider being incorrect in the second dump and how did you create it?

Comment: I'm printing the parameter variable to check it's correct before sending. @Alnitak

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad it's very obviously not legal JSON

Comment: @User you missed my point - you can't just call `print()` on an object and expect to get legal JSON out.  You should be calling "some other" function to perform that conversion.

Comment: I'll be performing this, however the parameter variable stills needs to look like the correct example before sending: Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://api.exampledomain.co.uk/v1/user", parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)

Comment: Do you need it in that order also?  Because, `[String: AnyObject]` is an unordered array.

Comment: That rearranged the order, however it still gives the wrong format.

Comment: @User that line of code should be in the question, not the comments

Comment: OK, so now how do you know that the data looks like that?  Is this perhaps what you're seeing once you've decoded the data on the server side?

Comment: I know the first example is correct, because it succeeds when I use that in postman.

Comment: @User that's not what I asked - I want to know how you displayed the data shown in the _second_ block.

Comment: I just did print(JSONResponce)

Comment: Right, and per above, that clearly won't work because the `print()` function _doesn't produce JSON_.  If there's an error, you need to tell us what it is, and whether it's produced by the client or the server.

Comment: @Alnitak This is *exactly* the reason for my question, how he produces the output. Got it now?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad he already answered that - he just uses `print()` which won't produce JSON.  However the Animofire `.request()` function is perfectly capable of converting a `Dictionary` into legal JSON as it sends it, but the OP has completely failed to indicate why they think their code doesn't behave as required.

Comment: @Alnitak I know. But not, when I asked for. Therefore I wrote: *This is* exactly *the reason for my question, how he produces the output. Got it now?*

Answer (score 1):

The underlying `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject()` function used by Alamofire cannot convert an `NSDate()` object into legal JSON, and will throw an exception when you try.

You therefore need to convert that `timestamp` object into a string value first, and then add it to the `account` object.

```
import Foundation

let firstName: String? = "Bob"
let lastName: String? = "Smith"
let email: String? = "bob@live.com"
let password: String? = "1234"

var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "Y-MM-dd H:mm:ss +0000"
let nsdateString: String = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

let account: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "first_name": firstName!,
    "last_name": lastName!,
    "email": email!,
    "password": password!,
//  "timestamp": NSDate()    // <-- causes an exception if uncommented
    "timestamp": nsdateString   // already converted to string
]

let gender: String? = "Male"
let date: String? = "08 Jul 2001"
let barberType: String? = "1"

let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [ "gender": gender!, "dob": date!, "loyalty_points": "0", "barber_type": barberType!, "account":

let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: .PrettyPrinted)
let str = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

print(str!)
```

with output:

```
{
  "loyalty_points" : "0",
  "account" : {
    "first_name" : "Bob",
    "last_name" : "Smith",
    "email" : "bob@live.com",
    "password" : "1234",
    "timestamp" : "2016-07-08 22:02:50 +0000"
  },
  "gender" : "Male",
  "barber_type" : "1",
  "dob" : "08 Jul 2001"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want the same format for each persons' information, which it looks like you do, then don't waste time with `arrays` when you can use a `string`.

Swift example code:

```
let gender = "Male"           // Test data
let date = "08 Jul 2001"
let loyalty_points = 0
let barberType = 1
let firstName = "Bob"
let lastName = "Smith"
let email = "bob@live.com"
let password = "1234"

let jsonstring = "{\t\"gender\": \"\(gender)\",\n\t\"dob\": \"\(date)\",   \n\t\"loyalty_points\": \"\(loyalty_points)\",\n\t\"barber_type\": \"\(barberType)\",\t \n\t\"account\": {\t\t\n\t\t\"first_name\": \"\(firstName)\",\t\t\n\t\t\"last_name\": \"\(lastName)\",\t\n\t\t\"email\": \"\(email)\",\t\t\n\t\t\"password\": \"\(password)\",\t\t \n\t\t\"timestamp\": \"\(NSDate())\"\t\n\t}\n}"

print(jsonstring)    // Output the JSON code
```

Result:

```
{   "gender": "Male",   
    "dob": "08 Jul 2001",   
    "loyalty_points": "0",  
    "barber_type": "1",  
    "account": {        
        "first_name": "Bob",        
        "last_name": "Smith",      
        "email": "bob@live.com",        
        "password": "1234",      
        "timestamp": "2016-07-08 17:18:34 +0000"    
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hand serialising JSON is a sure fire way to produce broken JSON.

Comment: Do you suggest a better way? @Alnitak

Comment: @User you haven't explained why you think you have a problem.  The `print()` function doesn't output JSON, so it's simply impossible to compare that with the output you think you should be getting, and you haven't demonstrated what output you're *really* getting out of the Alamofire POST call.

Comment: I don't know why I am having a problem. All I want to do is send a JSON value using a POST request, with the JSON looking like the first example I posted.

Comment: So _please tell us what problem you are actually experiencing!_  Error messages, debug output, whatever!